# <memory cannot be printed> note: pointer points here

Tags: c

I am a beginner in c.

I am trying to create a simple hashtable with the below code. However, error of below occurs. Anyone can explain why to me?

runtime error: store to misaligned address 0x0000ffffffff for type 'struct Node *', which requires 8 byte alignment
0x0000ffffffff: note: pointer points here

Segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Hashnode
{
    int size;
    struct Node** hashnode;
}Hashtable;


typedef struct Node
{
    char* word;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

int main(void)
{
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->word = "Elvin";
    node->next = NULL;
    printf("First Node created successfully!...\n");

    Hashtable hasht;

    hasht.size = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < hasht.size; i++)
    {
        hasht.hashnode[i] = NULL;
        printf("the address of the %i hasnode is: %p\n", i, hasht.hashnode[i]);
    }
    printf("The hashtable is created successfully!...\n");
```

Follow up questions

After correcting above code, i would like to link the hashnode with the node. As hashnode is the Node** (a pointer to pointer of node), hence the value of hasnode should be the address of node pointer (i.e. &node). my code is below.

However, it shows an error to me that incompatible pointer types assigning to 'struct Node *' from 'Node **' (aka 'struct Node **'); remove &.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Hashnode
{
    int size;
    struct Node** hashnode;
}Hashtable;


typedef struct Node
{
    char* word;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

int main(void)
{
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->word = "Elvin";
    node->next = NULL;
    printf("First Node created successfully!...\n");

    Hashtable hasht;

    hasht.size = 10;
    hasht.hashnode = malloc(sizeof(*hasht.hashnode)*hasht.size);
    for (int i = 0; i < hasht.size; i++)
    {
        hasht.hashnode[i] = NULL;
        printf("the address of the %i hashnode is: %p\n", i, hasht.hashnode[i]);
    }
    printf("The hashtable is created successfully!...\n");

    int key = 3;
    hasht.hashnode[key] = &node;
}
```

any idea what i did wrong?

Comment: `hasht.hashnode` isn't initialized.

Comment: please post a [mcve].  so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user3629249 I have copied the full code for the follow up questions. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu17` )  Note: other compilers use different option to obtain the same thing

Comment: I have the below error and i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: Same errors even i have put a check !=NULL on the malloc function. Seems the malloc has conducted successfully. But the issue i have is on the hasht.hashnode[key] = &node which i dunno how to fix

Comment: note this field definition: `struct Node** hashnode;`  which is being set as a pointer to an array of `struct node`  by the call to `malloc()`.  Suggest modifying to: `struct Node* hashnode;`  ( note only a single `*` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're forgetting to initialize the table of pointers:

```
hasht.size = 10;
// you need to allocate the array of pointers
hasht.hashnode = malloc(sizeof(*hasht.hashnode)*hasht.size);
// now proceed with your loop
for (int i = 0; i < hasht.size; i++)
{
```

so when trying to initialize your pointers, you write in <s>the woods</s> an undefined location: undefined behaviour.

Comment: may i have the follow up questions on above? thanks a lot !!